# Keeping clear of SQL injections

Tags: sql, code-injection

If I make sure only alpha-numerical characters are used in queries I should be free of any SQL injections, right?

Comment: How will you be able to use required characters such as `()=+` etc?

Comment: @oded, don't forget comma's and quotes.

Comment: Maybe he/she meant in the input fields put into queries, rather than the query itself?

Comment: explain what you mean by "make sure". You don't mean "I will only allow alphanumerics in webform textboxes", right?

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close.  It's a question, it's pretty clear what's being asked, and it's very answerable.

Comment: @Dave Yes, if I ever need to query something the user wrote, and I remove "bad" characters, it should be impossible for a SQL injection to occur?

Comment: @BobKaufman make sure: To establish something without doubt; make certain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQL Injection Prevention CheatSheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Primary_Defenses)

Bullet points:

- Defense Option 1: Prepared Statements (Parameterized Queries)

  - ...how all developers should first be taught how to write database queries.
- Defense Option 2: Stored Procedures

  - ...when implemented safely.
- Defense Option 3: Escaping All User Supplied Input

  - ...frail compared to using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty difficult to write a useful query with only alpha-numeric characters.  Use paramterized queries, don't look for a non-shortcut shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, that's probably correct, since it would block using -- or similar trickery.  Most platforms these days have much more robust methods for properly escaping input and keeping it from affecting the database in unintended ways, however.